# UIResponder Notification?

Tags: ios, ios8

Is there any sort of `UIResponder Notification` sent from objects that become a first responder? Or any way to know whether any `UITextField` or `UITextView` gets keyboard focus.

I have a ton of `UITextFields`/`UItextViews` in my application, and would like to add an input accessory view to all of them, but was hoping to avoid individually adding it in code to all their locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your view controller to be a delegate of text views and text fields.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
```

And then set it (in code or in the storyboard)

```
self.textField.delegate = self;
self.textView.delegate = self;
```

Then add these methods to your view controller

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
}
```

These will be called when the user selects the textField/textView.

Comment: Yeah, I already have these methods in a bunch of view controllers. I was wondering though about abstracting the input accessory view to some other object to set it.